# Addictional Claim details from Azure getting null values

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, claims

I am using Azure AD Authentication for my APP Service i am able to get firstname, enterpriseid in .net application but not able to get additional claims country,locality and Geounit.

The team also added those additional claim details in Azure AD but i am getting null vallues.

These values i am able to get

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            Claim firstname = claimsIdentity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname").FirstOrDefault();
            Claim enterpriseid = claimsIdentity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name").FirstOrDefault();
```

The below additional claims i am getting null values

```
Claim Country = claimsIdentity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/country").FirstOrDefault();
            Claim locationid = claimsIdentity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/locality").FirstOrDefault();
            Claim GeoUnit = claimsIdentity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/tenant_ctry").FirstOrDefault();
```

Please suggest the solution for this issue

Comment: How did you add the additional claims? Could you pls provide any document you are following?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims    this is the url followed to add optional claims